# Retrieving records from the table with reference

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have this code of Pagination, actually it will retrieve all the records in my table student, what i want is to retrieve records with a reference by year level. here is the code:

thanks for your help!

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['level'])) {
    $_POST['level'] = "undefine";
}
$level = $_POST['level'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("kp_and_harang") or die(mysql_error());

if (!(isset($_GET['pagenum']))) {
    $pagenum = 1;
} else {
    $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
}
$data = mysql_query("SELECT id,surname,firstname,middlename,level FROM students") or die(mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($data);
$page_rows = 2;
$last = ceil($rows / $page_rows);

if ($pagenum < 1) {
    $pagenum = 1;
} elseif ($pagenum > $last) {
    $pagenum = $last;
}

$max = 'limit ' . ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows . ',' . $page_rows;
$data_p = mysql_query("SELECT *,LPAD(id,4,'0') as id FROM students $max ") or die(mysql_error());

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data_p)) {
    echo "<tr class='tr1'>";
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<td class='1'>" . $info['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='1'>" . $info['surname'] . ", " . $info['firstname'] . " " . $info['middlename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='1'>" . $info['level'] . "</td>";
    echo "</center>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<br>";
}
echo "<p>";
echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";
if ($pagenum == 1) {

} else {
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";
    echo "----";
    $previous = $pagenum - 1;
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";
}

echo " ---- ";

if ($pagenum == $last) {

} else {
    $next = $pagenum + 1;
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";
    echo "----";
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";
}
?>
```

Comment: I know this is oversaid, but you should be using the mysqli php pluggin.

Comment: Here is a link on how to get started. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "retrieve records with a reference by year level" do you mean sort by year?

Comment: yup. i want to sort them by level..

Comment: Ok, my answer should work for you.

Comment: i have a combo box, when i choose, example, grade 1, all grade 1 should be displayed.

Comment: grade = level I assume?

Comment: yes! more like level = grade 1, all grade 1 students should be retrieve.

Comment: Updated my answer, try that.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrote your code to use mysqli.

As well, you just needed to add a "where" to you sql query.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['level'])) {
    $_POST['level'] = "undefined";
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$level = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['level']);

if (!(isset($_GET['pagenum']))) {
    $pagenum = 1;
} else {
    $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
}
$query = "SELECT id,surname,firstname,middlename,level FROM students";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$rows = $result->num_rows;
$page_rows = 2;
$last = ceil($rows / $page_rows);

if ($pagenum < 1) {
    $pagenum = 1;
} elseif ($pagenum > $last) {
    $pagenum = $last;
}

$max = 'limit ' . ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows . ',' . $page_rows;
if ($level == "undefined"){
$query = "SELECT *,LPAD(id,4,'0') as id FROM students $max" ORDER BY level;}
else{
$query = "SELECT *,LPAD(id,4,'0') as id FROM students $max where level = '$level' ORDER BY level";}
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
while ($info = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    echo "<tr class='tr1'>";
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<td class='1'>" . $info['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='1'>" . $info['surname'] . ", " . $info['firstname'] . " " . $info['middlename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='1'>" . $info['level'] . "</td>";
    echo "</center>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<br>";
}
echo "<p>";
echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";
if ($pagenum == 1) {

} else {
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";
    echo "----";
    $previous = $pagenum - 1;
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";
}

echo " ---- ";

if ($pagenum == $last) {

} else {
    $next = $pagenum + 1;
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";
    echo "----";
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";
}
?>
```

As well, this code was meant to match your code as close as possible, however... a much better way would be to make level an int value, as well using a case with default being the line `$query = "SELECT *,LPAD(id,4,'0') as id FROM students $max";`.

Comment: it has error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: Sorry, missed a semicolon there!

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where level = 'undefine'' at line 1190

Comment: Can you give me a link to the demo?

Comment: Nevermind. I changed your "undefined" to match my if statement that looks for if it is invalid. It should work now I believe.

Comment: Oh, are you using localhost to demo?

Comment: Try that code, I just wrote the if statment different that your "level not picked" set var

Comment: I added `ORDER BY level` into the query